# Formatting generated numbers in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, set

Forgive me if there is a simple answer to this, I'm new to all of this.

The below .bat script generates a list of numbers depending on how many numbers you want.

However what I would like is to format the numbers it generate.

For example, if I input 20, instead of it coming out 1, 2, 3 etc. I would like it to come out as 001, 002... 020.

Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Many Thanks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
:start
cls
set /p loopcount= How Many Users?: 
set "x="0"
:loop
set /a "x+=1"
echo %x%
set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if %loopcount%==0 goto exitloop
goto loop

:exitloop
pause
goto start
```

Comment: FWIW, applications like this are *way beyond* what batch file scripting was intended for. An equivalent script written in Python, PowerShell, C#, or even C, would be easier to write, easier to read, and have more powerful capabilities.

Comment: @Sneftel - it's not _that_ hard in batch; you just concatenate a bunch of zeroes at the beginning of the string and then take a substring of the last N characters.

Comment: Awesome. Meanwhile, in a modern programming language: `for i in range(int(input("How many users?"))): print("%03d" % i)`

Answer (score 1):

just implementing SomethingDark's suggestion (and a minor change in the logic of the loop):

```
set /p "loopcount= How Many Users?: "
set "x=1000"
:loop
  set /a x+=1
  echo %x:~-3%
  set /a loopcount-=1
  if %loopcount% gtr 0 goto :loop
echo loop finished.
```

(btw: your `set "x="0"` has a quote too much (probably a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example batch file which uses powershell for your leading zeroes.

I have used a for loop as the looping mechanism.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:AskNum
Set "num=1"
Set /P "num=how many users?"
Set num | findstr.exe /RX "^num=[123456789][0123456789]*$" 1>NUL || GoTo AskNum
For /F %%G In ('powershell.exe "1..%num% | %% ToString User000"') Do Echo %%G

Pause
```

*This script will not continue unless the end user inputs an integer, without a leading `0`, and which is a minimum value of `1`. Here you can modify the `Echo` command in `Do` to an alternative, for example `net.exe User %%G /Add`, or if you wish, to a parenthesized sequence of commands. In each case `%%G` will contain the returned string with the incremented three digits.This version prepends each three digit number sequence with an additional string, (`User`), but that can simply be deleted or replaced if/as required.*

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /p "lastnum= How many numbers? "
SET /a lastnum+=1000
FOR /L %%e IN (1001,1,%lastnum%) DO SET /a num=%%e&ECHO !num:~-3! 
GOTO :EOF
```

No need for complication